# Tri-head linux system with Xmonad: is it possible to have HW acceleration

Tags: linux, xorg, xmonad, xinerama

What means there exists to have three monitors, all controlled by Xmonad and have hardware 3D acceleration as well?

I had the pleasure of using three monitors earlier this year, and while Xmonad and Xinerama handle three monitors easily, I had to throw in an extra display driver, and also let go of Nvidia's own TwinView (which is a hack on Xinerama). This left me with no HW acceleration and some flickering as double buffering wouldn't work with certain applications. However, the three monitors handle so beautifully that I had hard time coming back to two.

I understand the easiest way to achieve HW-accelerated tri-head combo is to split into two Xorgs. I wouldn't be able to switch windows between the Xorgs, so I'm not really into this solution.

What's more, having a cheap and old PCI card along with even slightly better PCIe seemed to slow things down. Even if I occasionally disabled the third monitor from Xorg configure, I couldn't get HW acceleration to work. Only after I physically disconnected the old PCI card, I could get the games back in business.

Would a **Matrox Dual/Tri-head2go** and a powerful Nvidia GPU do the trick? I understand Xmonad can be configured to "believe" that a "single" (as Dualhead2Go will merge) 3360x1050 display is actually two different ones? So that Xmonad's `Mod-w` and `Mod-e` would work properly there.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/476012/linux-nvidia-surround-3-monitors development develops. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xdmx + Chromium? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdmx

If you really need 3D speed over 1-2 monitors and want to have only shared keyboard/mouse (two XMonads though) - get Synergy2.

Comment: What I just want is to get three monitors, controlled by single Xmonad in a manner such that I can throw windows from any display to another. Plus I want to have an occasional game session in windowed, one display. Hence the Synergy2 doesn't match my former requirement fully. I could live with that only two monitors out of three handled 3D acceleration.

Comment: Xdmx on top of two xorg's will give you that. However, it has bad opengl support (guess 1.4/1.5 max), and affects performance. Xdmx + chromium will be faster, but beware of bugs.